# Sum of complex number in polar form

Tags: real-analysis

I know that you can multiply complex numbers in polar form. How about adding complex numbers? Are there any ways to add 2 complex numbers in polar form without using algebraic form? For instance, I need to compute
$$(2+2i)^n + (2-2i)^n$$
So I tried to use the polar form to find the power of $n$. This what I got:
$$(2\sqrt{2})^n(\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}n)+i\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}n))+(2\sqrt{2})^n(\cos(-\frac{\pi}{4}n)+i\sin(-\frac{\pi}{4}n))$$
How do I proceed next?

Comment: Look up what it means for cosine to be an even function and sine to be an odd function and you will have a proper sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the $ \sin(\pi /4n)$ cancels with $ \sin(-\pi /4n)$ and your expression $$(2\sqrt{2})^n(\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}n)+i\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}n))+(2\sqrt{2})^n(\cos(-\frac{\pi}{4}n)+i\sin(-\frac{\pi}{4}n))$$

simplifies to $$2(2\sqrt{2})^n(\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}n)$$

Answer (score 1):

The most convenient way is to write them with their exponential form :

$$(2+2i)^n + (2-2i)^n= \left((2\sqrt{2})e^{i \frac{\pi}{4}}\right)^n + \left((2\sqrt{2})e^{-i \frac{\pi}{4}}\right)^n = (2 \sqrt{2})^n \left( e^{in \frac{\pi}{4}} + e^{-in \frac{\pi}{4}} \right)$$

so you get  $$(2+2i)^n + (2-2i)^n= 2^{n+1} \sqrt{2}^n \cos\left( n \frac{\pi}{4} \right)$$